# Why my adapter is not working? How to solve NullPointerException Error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm building a news app. I'm getting Kotlin null pointer exception error. I have made list of channel names on clicking on it will show different news from those channel source but when I clicked on one of the news channel it gets crashed. can anyone help me with my code?
this is the error it's showing:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newswrld, PID: 16135
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.newswrld.Adapter.ViewHolder.ListNewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListNewsAdapter.kt:47)
        at com.example.newswrld.Adapter.ViewHolder.ListNewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ListNewsAdapter.kt:16)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2020-06-05 18:05:23.297 16135-16135/com.example.newswrld E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is ListNewsAdapter.kt:

```
package com.example.newswrld.Adapter.ViewHolder

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.newswrld.Common.ISO8601Parser
import com.example.newswrld.Interface.ItemClickListener
import com.example.newswrld.Model.Article
import com.example.newswrld.R
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import java.text.ParseException
import java.util.*

class ListNewsAdapter(val articleList:MutableList<Article>, private val context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<ListNewsViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListNewsViewHolder {
        val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context)
        val itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_layout,parent,false)
        return ListNewsViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListNewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(articleList[position].urlToImage)
            .into(holder.article_image)

        if(articleList[position].title!!.length > 65){
            holder.article_title.text=articleList[position].title!!.substring(0,65)+"..."
        }
        else{
            holder.article_title.text=articleList[position].title!!
        }
        if(articleList[position].publishedAt!=null){
            var date: Date?=null
            try {
                date=ISO8601Parser.parse(articleList[position].publishedAt!!)
            }catch (ex:ParseException)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
            holder.article_time.setReferenceTime(date!!.time)
        }

        holder.setItemClickListener(object :ItemClickListener{
            override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

here is the link to Source code:https://github.com/xSankeTx/NewsWRLD

Comment: please post full logcat stacktrace

Comment: Error seems to come from `date!!.time`.

Comment: date was not parsed properly, it is null. Can you make sure it is not null by logging or printing it before calling `setReferenceTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this.

```
holder.setItemClickListener(object :ItemClickListener{
    override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {

    }
})
```

To this

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
     // do some action here
}
```

Your ViewHolder should look like this.

```
class ListSourceViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}
```

Comment: it's not working. if I add itemView, it's giving me an error and telling me to rename setItemClickListener.

Comment: Please post your viewholder class @SamMarlie

Comment: @AnimeshSahu damn. I haven't noticed. I have now updated my answer to kotlin.

Comment: no. it still the same, not working @elbertrivas. here is the view holder class: https://pastebin.com/GXJzJUYU

Comment: @SamMarlie check my updated answer. Just remove other codes.

Comment: nothing. can you have a look in my repo once? @elbertrivas

Answer (score 0):

Usually KotlinNullPointerException cause !! operator. All properties of your Article model
(https://github.com/xSankeTx/NewsWRLD/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/newswrld/Model/Article.kt) declared as nullable. Try to handle all nullable properties with `?.let {}` function like this:

```
article.title?.let {
   // Use title safely by `it`
}
```

Operator **!!** should be avoided in most cases.